# How do I increase max fuel in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

A trip between star systems could easily use up 500 units. How can I increase the maximum fuel capacity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you can...but you can salvage fuel by scanning ship remains.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to increase the Normandy's fuel reserves in ME3. However if you travel around the map you might get a light ping when you hit a certain area (similar noise to when you approach a planet). Actively pinging in close proximity to this hidden planet will reveal a destroyed fuel depot which will give you a one time fuel refill of X amount of fuel. There's usually one in each system. However revisiting this destroyed depot will not refuel you.

WARNING: locating this hidden fuel depot may attract Reapers.

Answer (score -1):

You CAN increase the fuel capacity by editing coalased.ini file.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This could be a decent answer (if probably limited to the PC version), but it lacks a great deal of necessary information to be a good ***useful*** answer. Namely, two things; where is the file located, and where within that .ini file is the value you must change (and to what?). Just telling us a thing is possible without saying how or under what conditions (PC only), is not a very good answer.