# Are there any upgrades availiable for the Normandy to help me evade Reapers while gathering resources?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So, the Normandy is pretty cool. Her scanners have been upgraded, and I can check a few planets at once now to see if they have a shiny rock I might be interested in. Unfortunately, those scanners [attract unwelcome attention](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53635/what-happens-if-the-reapers-catch-me-while-im-scanning).

I don't like Reapers, and running away from them in between scanning planets is tedious -  *especially* when I have to go running in search of a fuel depot every third system I visit.

In Mass Effect 2, I could upgrade the Normandy's scanners and fuel tanks, to make scanning more efficient and to allow for fewer trips to a fuel depot in between systems.

Are there any upgrades availiable that will improve the Normandy's speed (to run away more better), range (either through higher fuel capacity or more fuel efficiency, to visit more systems before needing to find a relay/fuel), or scanning efficiency/range (In order to send out fewer pings and alert fewer annoying Reapers)?

Comment: Fuel Efficiency question has a [dupe](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53621/336) but this question goes beyond that, so it doesn't need to be closed as such.

Comment: Related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54205/10260

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can only find war assets and fuel from crashed ships.

Answer (score -3):

through scanning you can find upgrades like the thaxis cannon for the normandy. they appear as war assets.

EDIT: they dont affect gameplay outside of war assets. so there arent any ME2 style ship upgrades

Comment: Do these War Asset upgrades in any way affect gameplay? Or are they purely useful for increasing the readiness counter towards endgame? If the latter, this does not answer the question.